# Expand div from center of the body using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How could I expand / grow a div from center?
It currently expands from top left to bottom right. Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adwb4q9x/1/).

```
<div class="growme">test</div>
```

```js
$('.growme').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    opacity: 1,
}, 'normal');
```

```css
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adwb4q9x/2/

Answer (score 5):

Try this make your `.growme` class center of the body. by adding top, left,bottom and right as 0.

```js
$('.growme').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    opacity: 1,
}, 'normal');
```

```css
.growme {
    background-color: #990000;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="growme">test</div>
```

**

### OR

**

You can also use `transition` for the same.

```js
$('.growme').animate({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    opacity: 1,
}, 'normal');
```

```css
.growme {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #990000;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="growme">test</div>
```

Comment: great! this is working as expected! thanks so much @akash

Comment: @user1781041 I am so happy to help you.